# Timeout using ServiceStack.Client

Tags: httpwebrequest, servicestack, webmethod

I have been using service stack via AJAX calls for some time without issue, but have recently created a quick winforms app which utilizes the service stack client (specifically JsonServiceClient).

However - I have hit a problem whereby I consistently get a timeout on a call which works successfully on the the first TWO attempts.  It looks like either the service stack client is holding on to some resource, or I am using the client in the wrong way.  It only occurs when running against a remote service (works every time on a local machine).  Here is my code, and the exception:

```
        var url = "http://www.TestServer.com/api";
        var taskId = Guid.Parse("30fed418-214b-e411-80c1-22000a5b9fe5");
        var email = "admin@example.com";

        using (var client = new JsonServiceClient(url))
        {
            var result = client.Send(new Authenticate {UserName = "username", Password = "Password01", RememberMe = true});
            client.Put(new AssignTask { AdminTaskId = taskId, Assignee = email });//Call #1 - works fine
            client.Put(new AssignTask { AdminTaskId = taskId, Assignee = email });//Call #2 - works fine

            try
            {
                client.Put(new AssignTask { AdminTaskId = taskId, Assignee = email });//Call #3 - works fine
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                //Times out every time
               //at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
               //at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
               //at ServiceStack.Net40PclExport.GetRequestStream(WebRequest webRequest)
               //at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.<>c__DisplayClassa.<SendRequest>b__9(HttpWebRequest client)
               //at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.PrepareWebRequest(String httpMethod, String requestUri, Object request, Action`1 sendRequestAction)
               //at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.SendRequest(String httpMethod, String requestUri, Object request)
               //at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.Send[TResponse](String httpMethod, String relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, Object request)
               //at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.Put[TResponse](String relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, Object requestDto)
               //at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.Put(Object requestDto)
               //at SSClientIssue.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\David\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SSClientIssue\SSClientIssue\Program.cs:line 27
                throw;
            }

        }
```

After the timeout, I can close and reload the app (server stays up), and then get same behavior again (two successful calls).  IIS logs show that the 3rd call does not make it to the server, so looks like a Client issue.

I have been looking at this for 8 hours and I think my eyes are starting to bleed...If anyone can help I will buy you a beer!

Comment: What's the best way to be able to repro this? Can you add a self-contained example in a GitHub repro or link to a .zip that we can run locally?

Comment: Sorry Mythz - was away with a new baby!  I have added the repro to GitHub (https://github.com/hiblen/SSIssue).  One thing to notice, is that the issue only occurs when the client and service are on different machines (over the internet against an AWS instance in my case).  I suspect this is because of a connection limit in Windows...I may be wrong.  The client code shows where the error is thrown.  Shout if you need any more details...would love to get this solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is due to your `ServiceClient` requests not specifying a known response type.

Response types can either be marked on the Request DTO using the `IReturn<T>` marker (recommended):

```
public class GetAllAdminUsernamesRequest : IReturn<List<string>> { ... }
```

By adding this on the Request DTO, the ServiceClient is able to automatically infer and convert the response, e.g:

```
List<string> response = client.Get(new GetCurrentAdminUserAdminTasks());
```

Otherwise an alternative to specifying the Response on the Request DTO, is to specify it on the call-site, e.g:

```
List<string> response = client.Get<List<string>>(new GetCurrentAdminUserAdminTasks());
```

If you don't do this the Response is unknown so the ServiceClient will just return the underlying `HttpWebResponse` so you can inspect the response yourself.

```
HttpWebResponse tasks = client.Get(new GetCurrentAdminUserAdminTasks());
```

In order to be able to inspect and read from the `HttpWebResponse` the response cannot be disposed by the ServiceClient, so it's up to the call-site making the request to properly dispose of it, i.e:

```
using (HttpWebResponse tasks = client.Get(new GetCurrentAdminUserAdminTasks())) {}
using (HttpWebResponse adminUsers = client.Get(new GetAllAdminUsernames())) {}

try
{
    using (client.Put(new AssignTask { AdminTaskId = taskId, Assignee = user })) {}
    using (client.Put(new AssignTask { AdminTaskId = taskId, Assignee = user })) {}
    using (client.Put(new AssignTask { AdminTaskId = taskId, Assignee = user })) {}
    using (client.Put(new AssignTask { AdminTaskId = taskId, Assignee = user })) {}
}
...
```

Disposing of your WebResponses responses will resolve your issue.

If you don't do this the underlying `WebRequest` will throttle open connections and only let a limited number of simultaneous connections through at any one time, possibly as a safe-guard to prevent DDOS attacks. This is what keeps the underlying connections open and `WebRequest` to block, waiting for them to be released.

Comment: How would you handle async requests wrt disposing? I'm using Success and Error callbacks (via the extension methods) on the returned Task<T> from PostAsync. Would I call Dispose on the WebResponse within my callbacks?

Comment: @mythz I have same question as AndyMoose, I have been getting service timeout intermittent issues even though my responses are typed in both requests DTOs and Xamarin.iOS Client .. I'm using success and error callback so do we need to do anything special in that case ?

Comment: @MohammadZekrallah There may be some issues with Xamarin's impl of .NET's HttpWebRequest on iOS. Can you try instead using the new [JsonHttpClient that's based on HttpClient](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/xamarin-system-net-vs-native-nsurlsession-performance-in-servicestack/921/6?u=mythz) which lets you use [ModernHttpClient](https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient).

Comment: @mythz that was super quick ! of course ..  I will try it and post my results here and in service stack issues tracker if anything goes wrong ..

Comment: I have been looking into modern http client a bit but I'm afraid that project is not that mature enough for production use especially after i've seen its issues in the github repo .. @mythz if you have some documented case or code where xamarin's implementation is proven faulty or needs more stabilization, please give it to me and I can hand it over to their support since I have a paid xamarin license. Thanks

Comment: @MohammadZekrallah A ServiceStack Customer has reported occaisional 3G issues with HttpWebRequest where Xamarin support has advised them that they should try to use ModernHttpClient instead which is what prompted development of JsonHttpClient. Would be cool if you could find out what the supported .NET client for Xamarin platforms and whether they'll support issues in HttpWebRequest, ModernHttpClient or HttpClient.

Comment: sure @mythz .. anytime .. here is their response:

"We do suggest, at this time, using ModernHttpClient for these purposes. While we can not provide direct support to that item specifically, such as if there is a bug within ModernHttpClient, but we can still support your Xamarin items, even if you are using a third party library. That is to say, using a third party library does not void support :)

We hope to have many of the bugs fixed with HTTPWebRequest and other networking classes resolved and improved over the coming months. But at this point, I would still suggest using ModernHTTPClient"

Comment: @MohammadZekrallah ok thx, looks like they're recommending ModernHttpClient atm, which for SS on iOS would mean using the new JsonHttpClient configured with ModernHttpClient NativeMessageHandler.