# Timeout using ServiceStack Client on same machine as the Service Host

Tags: servicestack

We've deployed our code to another environment and now we are seeing this exception in the logs and would like to try to narrow the issue down to the environment or my code.

```
System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.Send[TResponse](String httpMethod, String relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, Object request)
   at LO.Leads.Processor.ProcessorAppHost.<>c__DisplayClass23.<ConfigureRabbitMqServer>b__20(IMessage`1 m) in c:\repo\AppHost.cs:line 171
```

The code works, and has worked in the lower environments for months, but did not have the load that this one does.

After a bit of reading I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483395/timeout-using-servicestack-client) post that is somewhat similar in that the timeout occurs after x number of usages but we are using the client in the proper fashion (disposing of the response and the client) and the service is crafted to facilitate the client e.g. IReturn

code from the windows service:

```
mqServer.RegisterHandler<LeadInformationInfo>(m =>
{
    var messageBody = m.GetBody();
    var id = messageBody.CorrelationId;
    _log.InfoFormat("CorrelationId:{0} mqServer.RegisterHandler<LeadInformationInfo>", id);
    container.Resolve<IFrontEndRepository>().SaveMessage(m as Message);
    LeadInformationInfoResponse response;
    try
    {
        using (var client = new JsonServiceClient(container.Resolve<ISettingsFactory>().GetMasterSetting("ProcessorApi:baseUri")))
        {
            response = client.Post(messageBody);
        }
    }
    catch (WebServiceException webServiceException)
    {
        _log.ErrorFormat("CorrelationId:{0} webServiceException:{1}", id, webServiceException);
        _log.ErrorFormat("CorrelationId:{0} messageBody:{1}", id, messageBody.Dump());
        response = ((LeadInformationInfoResponse)webServiceException.ResponseDto);
        response.CorrelationId = id;
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        _log.ErrorFormat("CorrelationId:{0} exception:{1} body:{2}", id, exception, messageBody);
        return null;
    }
    var responseMessage = new Message<LeadInformationInfoResponse>(response)
    {
        ReplyId = m.Id
    };
    container.Resolve<IFrontEndRepository>().SaveMessage(responseMessage);
    _log.InfoFormat("CorrelationId:{0} mqServer.RegisterHandler<LeadInformationInfo> final", id);
    return response;
}, 8);
```

code from the service:

```
public object Post(LeadInformationInfo request)
{
    if (request == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
    var profiler = Profiler.Current;
    using (profiler.Step("Direct API POST"))
    {
        if (_log.IsDebugEnabled)
            _log.DebugFormat("CorrelationId:{0} LeadInformationInfo request:{1}", request.CorrelationId, request.Dump());
        var id = request.CorrelationId;
        using (profiler.Step("Set defaults"))
        {
            request.SetDefaults();
            request.LeadApplicationInfo.FixBankData();    
        }
        PreprocessInfoResponse preprocessResponse;
        using (profiler.Step("Preprocess"))
        using (var service = ResolveService<PreprocessServices>())
        {
            var preprocessRequest = request.LeadApplicationInfo.ConvertTo<PreprocessInfo>();
            preprocessResponse = service.Get(preprocessRequest);
            if (_log.IsDebugEnabled)
                _log.DebugFormat("CorrelationId:{0} LeadInformationInfo preprocessResponse:{1}", id, preprocessResponse.Dump());
            request.LeadApplicationInfo.PopulateWithNonDefaultValues(preprocessResponse);
        }
        if (_log.IsDebugEnabled)
            _log.DebugFormat("CorrelationId:{0} LeadInformationInfo updated request:{1}", id, request.Dump());
        AddLeadResponse saveLeadResponse;
        using (profiler.Step("Save lead"))
        {
            saveLeadResponse = SaveLead(request);
        }

        var leadInformationResponse = new LeadInformationInfoResponse
        {
            CorrelationId = id,
            LeadId = saveLeadResponse.LeadId,
            IsValidLead = preprocessResponse.IsValidLead,
            ValidStatus = preprocessResponse.LeadStatus,
        };

        if (!preprocessResponse.IsValidLead)
        {
            var unprocessedLead = new UnprocessedLead
            {
                TenantId = request.TenantId,
                CorrelationId = id,
                LeadId = saveLeadResponse.LeadId,
                ValidStatus = preprocessResponse.LeadStatus,
                AgentQueue = preprocessResponse.AgentQueue,
            };
            _log.WarnFormat("CorrelationId:{0} unprocessedLead:{0}", id, unprocessedLead.Dump());
            using (var client = MessageFactory.CreateMessageQueueClient())
            {
                client.Publish(unprocessedLead);
            }
            if (_log.IsDebugEnabled)
                _log.DebugFormat("CorrelationId:{0} LeadInformationInfo unprocessed lead leadInformationResponse:{1}", id, leadInformationResponse.Dump());
            return leadInformationResponse;
        }

        var outboundInitiateCallInfo = new OutboundInitiateCallInfo
        {
            TenantId = request.TenantId,
            CorrelationId = id,
            LeadId = saveLeadResponse.LeadId,
            LeadPhoneNumber = request.LeadApplicationInfo.Phones.First(),
            AgentQueue = preprocessResponse.AgentQueue,
        };
        _log.InfoFormat("CorrelationId:{0} outboundInitiateCallInfo:{0}", id, outboundInitiateCallInfo.Dump());
        using (var client = MessageFactory.CreateMessageQueueClient())
        {
            client.Publish(outboundInitiateCallInfo);
        }
        if (_log.IsDebugEnabled)
            _log.DebugFormat("CorrelationId:{0} LeadInformationInfo outbound phone lead leadInformationResponse:{1}", id, leadInformationResponse.Dump());
        return leadInformationResponse;      
    }
}
```

Request and Response DTOs:

```
public class LeadInformationInfo : IForTenant, IAudit, IReturn<LeadInformationInfoResponse>
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public LeadApplicationInfo LeadApplicationInfo { get; set; }
    public RequestInfo RequestInfo { get; set; }
    public long CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public long ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
}

public class LeadInformationInfoResponse
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public bool IsValidLead { get; set; }
    public string LeadId { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
    public string ValidStatus { get; set; }
}
```

So my question would be how do I diagnose this error to get to the root cause, if the code is correct?, or is there a better way to communicate to the web service using ServiceStack and thus getting rid of the web request object entirely?

Thank you, Stephen

Comment: Don't see anything obvious, maybe it's just a load issue? Do you know how many simultaneous requests are pending at the time the Timeout is thrown? You can try increasing the Timeouts on the client, otherwise you might want to consider adding retry logic.

Comment: There is no load, 3 people from QA instead of 1 :( I did notice that the timeout on the client is null by default, but that really means 30 seconds. What's your preferred way of capturing pending requests so i can get you that number. Can't do retry on this, it has to succeed the first time.

Comment: I would just have a static counter that I'd increment before and decrement after the service call.