# Using multiple instances of ServerEventsClient in single process connecting to same service URI

Tags: servicestack, server-sent-events

When I use multiple ServerEventsClient instances in a single .NET application connecting to same URI, any subsequent GET/POST etc call blocks indefinitely and times out. I believe this is related to some DDoS protection as mentioned in this answer by @mythz ([Timeout using ServiceStack.Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483395/timeout-using-servicestack-client)). And this happens only when the server and client are not running on the same PC.

I can work around this by ensuring that I only make one ServerEventsClient for a given URI, but before I put in too much work, I want to make sure that this is by design and there are no simpler work-arounds for handling this. Has anybody else ran into this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServiceStack's [C# Server Events Client](https://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-server-events-client) uses .NET `HttpWebRequest` behind the scenes which has built-in request limit per domain.

You should be able to increase the limit by increasing [System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_ServicePointManager_DefaultConnectionLimit), e.g:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;
```

Alternatively you should be able to increase this limit with `<connectionManagement>` in your Web.config:

```
<configuration>  
  <system.net>  
    <connectionManagement>  
      <add address = "http://www.contoso.com" maxconnection = "4" />  
      <add address = "*" maxconnection = "10" />  
    </connectionManagement>  
  </system.net>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you @mythz. This fixes the issue and also helps me understand better. I might still add code to make sure to create only one ServerEventsClient per URI because no matter what the 'ConnectionLimit' is, I may theoretically run-out of connections. (I am writing a library that other apps will use so I cant predict and don't want to dictate how they use it).